# Socrata row throttling when downloading files

Tags: socrata, soda

I'm trying to download csv files from state dataset, for analysis locally. The state in question runs on the [Socrata](https://dev.socrata.com/) platform. When hitting urls, CSV's are always returned.

For example, [https://data.mass.gov/resource/dnyu-v8e9.csv](https://data.mass.gov/resource/dnyu-v8e9.csv&&$$app_token=xxxx) supposedly has 12.9K rows. When downloading, I sometimes get a CSV file with 12.9K rows. Other times, it's 1001 rows, and at least once, it was 5 rows.

Is there a way around this restriction? It doesn't seem to be documented.

Answer (score 0):

There's some undocumented behavior when hitting the SODA api url. You can bypass this by using the site's web addresses. For instance, dnyu-v8e9 is a dataset hosted by Cambridge, MA, which is a part of the MA federation. So instead of

https://data.mass.gov/resource/dnyu-v8e9.csv

try

https://data.cambridgema.gov/api/views/dnyu-v8e9/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD